# Simpler way to add eth0 support in initrd.img (Centos)

Tags: linux, nfs, kernel, pxe-boot, initramfs

I am trying to deploy clone image via pxeboot on hard disk. For this I want to use dd tool. I am aware that there are few tools like fog and clonezilla which does similar thing but this is university project.

Background:

Currently I am deploying VMlinuz and initrd.img via pxeboot and since this gives me environment to run my bash script, after loading is completed I do dd to deploy image on hard disk. This works fine.

Question:
Now instead of packing disk image in initrd.img (which is very expensive) I want to mount nfs which resides on pxe server. But when initrd gets loaded and I try to ping pxe server it gives error "Network not reachable"

I tried to find RC and I believe that eth0 is not configured and I don't have ip address. I further tried to find a way to enable this eth0 but one way involves modification of intramfs which is very new to me. Can anyone help me here to get some starting points.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what happens. When you PXE boot vmlinuz/initrd the net transfer of both files are performed supported by the PXE "UNDI" net driver located at your client's PXE firmware.
From the moment vmlinuz is alive and it has mounted initrd the PXE UNDI driver is not used anymore now the corresponding `Linux` net driver is used instead `("if available")`.

From what you say it seems to me you are using a vmlinuz/initrd set that `does not have net support` or probably you are messing with the init script and you are invoking the `ping` services before init sets the Linux network services up.

When a vmlinuz/initrd set does have net support you will see when the kernel starts a new DHCP request as it need to initialize its NIC/s despite the UNDI driver has done exactly the same just seconds ago before transferring vmlinuz/initrd. Then you can see if your set has net support or not by confirming if there are 1 or 2 DHCP request; or just see init's code.

if your set does not have net support just get a new set. You can find lot of kernel/initrd sets with net suports on [Serva's](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html) page.
Please consider `depending on the set` there are certain syslinux parameters that must be appended in order to properly set the net services like i.e. `ipappend 2` and `ip=dhcp` or `ip=bootp` etc

Comment: Thanks Pat, Actually I placed my code at proper place but still after that only lo interface was available. So to configure eth0 I user ip link tool and it worked :).

Comment: ok in your case the net drivers were there but the init script was just not into the net initialization thing. good.